# Logic App Sql Connector as trigger fires many threads

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using a Sql Connector as a trigger in my Logic App

- **Action 1** - Trigger every two minutes with data available query as `select count(*) from Foo where status = "new"` and poll data query
  as `select id, name, status from foo where status = "new"`;
- **Action 2** - processes data;
- **Action 3** - uses another sql connector to update the foo table status to "complete";

As you can see from the [run image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJhis.png), several threads are kicked off for the one entry that is in my db.  Is this normal, a defect or just the wrong way to flow the app?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understood that you put two SQL Connectors one to poll the data and one to update the data which is polled.

If above is the case mean you are going wrong direction you should not use 2 SQL Connectors to complete your work. you should write update statement in your polled query only.

EX: `select id, name, status from foo where status = "new";UPDATE foo SET status='complete' WHERE status = 'new'`
simply append your update query with semicolon as delimiter

Comment: My goal was to only update the status upon successful completion of the full logic app.  I want the status to remain "new" on failure so that a retry/replay can happen.  I've seen some examples doing what you mention but it is undesirable given that transactions are not supported across the full workflow.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: @WadeB why don't you create a middle status like in-progress. select with status new and same update with status in-progress; if your workflow fails change status again to new otherwise make it complete

Comment: Thanks Ramakrishna, I think the middle status would work fine.  I have considered that.  I'm hoping someone can shed some light on why and how so many threads kick off at once.  I would like to understand the inner design better so I can ensure that even with the "read and update" in trigger, i will not get redundant actions.